# OnsenUI myNavigator.pushPage() not working

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

When using `myNavigator.pushPage('settings.html', {param1: 'bla'});menu.closeMenu()` to move a user to a new page, the redirected page includes a logout button, this button does not work if user is redirected using the pushPage() way, but works if I use instead the code below:

```
 <ons-tabar><ons-tabbar-item page="settings.html"  icon="ion-pinpoint"></ons-tabbar-item> 
    </ons-tabbar>
```

Really strange problem, I dont know why all buttons on my page become inactive if I use pushPage(), if I add any button none of them work. I have the following code on my settings.html page (i.e. page user gets directed to)

```
<ons-row style="padding: 20px; text-align: center;">
    <ons-col >
         <ons-button modifier="large" style="background:#ccc" ng-click="logout()">Logout</ons-button>
     </ons-col>
</ons-row>
```

Above button only works if user clicks using `<ons-tabbar>` above but not this way:

```
  <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="myNavigator.pushPage('tags.html', {param1: 'bla'});menu.closeMenu()">
    <ons-row>
        <ons-col width="20%" align="left">
            <ons-icon icon="ion-ios-barcode-outline darkgrey"></ons-icon>
        </ons-col>
        <ons-col width="80%" align="left">
            <span style="padding-left:0.3em" align="right" >Tags</span>
        </ons-col>
    </ons-row>            
  </ons-list-item>
```

I am also getting this error pages that appears only sometimes:

> Cannot call method $new of null at Class.extend._createPageScope(...

Comment: Is this question the same as you asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451654/how-to-replace-page-tabbar-using-onsenui  If so, did the response by @fran-dios resolve your issue?